# Swift: How to convert Bytes into a float / get a more precise number?

Tags: swift, math, floating-point, byte, core-bluetooth

I am getting accelerometer data from a BLE device in the form of 6 bytes and I want to convert it into a floating point value to be as precise as possible.

Every 2 bytes represents a different axis, (x, y & z respectively). Instead of a number like 982, I want a number like 0.98243873

I've tried converting the bytes into a Float by trying...

```
let data = characteristic.value!

let floatX = Float(bitPattern:UInt32(littleEndian:data[0...1].withUnsafeBytes{$0.pointee}))

OR

let floatX = data[0...1].withUnsafeBytes{$0.pointee} as Float
```

but I am getting weird numbers like `-6.777109e-21` when the Int16 value is `1047` and I am expecting something like `1.04793283`. Would it have something to do with the bytes being signed? Can I even get precision like this from two bytes?

Comment: I wouldn't expect to get much precision from a 16-bit float.

Comment: What's the exact layout of the data? Are the bytes in little or big endian order?

Comment: Two-byte values may be encoded in variety of ways depending on devices. Please provide what device you are using and the data sheet about the accelerometer output of the device.

Comment: The two bytes are most likely simply an integer representing acceleration in some units (such as meters per second square or millimeters per second square or meters per second square times 256, or some other scaling). In that case, you could convert the measurement to floating-point simply by multiplying or dividing by whatever scaling you desired. There would not be any need to manipulate the bytes representing a floating-point object.

Comment: Why would you expect 1047 to become 1.04793203? Why would you not want 1047 to become 1.047, or as near to 1.047 as the floating-point type can represent?

Comment: @Eric: I guess he just made up the extra decimals because he did not know the exact value it would be. ISTM he meant "something **like** `1.047xyz` but certainly not `-6.777109e-21`".

Comment: @Alexander The data is in little endian order

Comment: @EricPostpischil. Rudy Velthuis summed it up perfectly. I do not know what the exact value would be

Comment: @G-VARSH Can you give us an executable test case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to turn little endian `UInt32` values into `Float` merely by "reinterpreting" the same bit patterns as a new value (that's what `Float(bitPattern:)` is for), but that's not at all how Float stores its data. Swift's `Float` and `Double` datatypes are implementations of the 32 and 64 bit floating point data types from [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). There's plenty of online resources that explain it, but the TL;DR is that they store numbers in a similar way as scientific notation, with a mantissa raised to the power of an exponent.

I think part of your difficulty comes from trying to do too much at once. Break it down into small pieces. Write a function that takes your data, and decomposes it into the 3 `UInt32` components. Then write a separate function that does whatever transformation you want on those components, such as turning them into floats. Here's a rough example:

```
import Foundation

func createTestData(x: UInt32, y: UInt32, z: UInt32) -> Data {
    return [x, y, z]
        .map { UInt32(littleEndian: $0) }
        .withUnsafeBufferPointer { Data(buffer: $0) }
}

func decode(data: Data) -> (x: UInt32, y: UInt32, z: UInt32) {
    let values = data.withUnsafeBytes { bufferPointer in
            bufferPointer
                .bindMemory(to: UInt32.self)
                .map { rawBitPattern in
                    return UInt32(littleEndian: rawBitPattern)
                }
        }

    assert(values.count == 3)
    return (x: values[0], y: values[1], z: values[2])
}

func transform(ints: (x: UInt32, y: UInt32, z: UInt32))
    -> (x: Float, y: Float, z: Float) {
    let transform: (UInt32) -> Float = { Float($0) / 1000 } // define whatever transformation you need
    return (transform(ints.x), transform(ints.y), transform(ints.z))
}

let testData = createTestData(x: 123, y: 456, z: 789)
print(testData) // => 12 bytes
let decodedVector = decode(data: testData)
print(decodedVector) // => (x: 123, y: 456, z: 789)
let intsToFloats = transform(ints: decodedVector)
print(intsToFloats) // => (x: 0.123, y: 0.456, z: 0.789)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you receive 6 bytes, where each 2 bytes represent an axis, you actually receive 3 numbers, 16 bit integers each. To turn them into the kind of float you want (where `1047` --> `1.047xxx`), you must obviously divide each of them by `1000.0`.

I don't know Swift, but simply do something like this pseudo-code:

```
x = (first_byte + 256 * second_byte) / 1000.0;  // or vice versa, if big-endian
y = (third_byte + 256 * fourth_byte) / 1000.0;  // same...
z = (fifth_byte + 256 * sixth_byte) / 1000.0;   // same again
```

As I indicated, if the bytes coming out of the device are big-endian, you obviously do:

```
x = (256 * first_byte + second_byte) / 1000.0; 
// etc...
```

You can perhaps speed this up a bit by multiplying by the reverse, i.e. `* 0.001`, because multiplication is usually a little faster than division. Some compilers do this for you, though, if they notice this is a constant:

```
x = (...) * 0.001;
```

Comment: thanks! It seems to be exactly what I am looking for. Will try it on Monday and update you!